# Ruby: Resize Images without ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to resize images in Ruby without ImageMagick.... and also without ruby-vips? Yes, I know I am being rather narrow, but can't seem to get both of them to install on my Mac,  which is kinda annoying. I just wanna resize, nothing fancy... anything lightweight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be ImageScience, but I'm getting a lot of broken links for it when googling now.

Might also try to find Ruby lib for GD or GD2.

Comment: Just tried installing ImageScience and there's been known issues for installing it on Rails on a Mac..

Comment: never mind, I was able to install it correctly. Just needed to resolve some dependency. thank for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Quick search on ruby gems.org leads to a few candidates:
http://rubygems.org/search?query=image+resize

Also, with regard to having trouble installing ImageMagick on your Mac. Do you know about [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)?